# How to execute datediff on multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do something like this:

`select datediff('2010-01-21',(select date_of_birth from people));`

and take as result the difference from each date_of_birth.

Comment: The answer depends on your database engine, which you didn't specify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [datediff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) to get Difference in terms of day or specified format (either month, week year, days etc)

```
select datediff(DAY,'2010-01-21',date_of_birth)
from people
```

Comment: downvoter:- specify why? any specific reason for your downvote? something is not workiing for you? or you have any other thought process? Lets discuss